# Sum of Columns for View

Tags: views

I have a view with the following results:

```
           penalty    attorney_fees   other 
client1    100,000    100,000         0

client2    50,000     75,000          10,000

client3    25,000     50,000          25,000

           total?     total?          total?
```

How do I get the sum of the column "total" for penalty, attorney_fees, and other?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc) module for that. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> ... adds simple calculations to a views table. Requires the Views module.
>
> You can SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT, MIN, MAX, or AVG selected columns. A plug in theme makes the view look more spreadsheet-like (right justifies numeric fields, shades calculated columns and rows, and underlines calculated rows).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I have already tried Views Calc with no luck.

Comment: What issues were you having? Views Calc seems like a good fit for this.  How many rows are you calculating at a time?

Comment: The Total SUM is amount is off.  For instance, the Total SUM of penalty is 175,000 but the Total SUM of attorney_fees is 0.

Comment: Views Calc it is possible to sum by cols? or rows

Answer (score 0):

you can download and install the [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) module then your problem is solved. This module allow to the sum functionality in there. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> ... As the **Views** and **Views Calc** modules rely on the database to perform aggregation, you only have limited options at your disposal. As the great Merlin himself said: "You can't aggregate a PHP expression in the database.".
>
> That's where Views Aggregator Plus comes in. In addition to what Views and Views Calc do, this module:
>
> - enumerates group members
> - produces tallies, i.e. textual histograms
> - aggregates on Views PHP code-snippet evalutations
> - can filter out result rows on regexp patterns
> - gives you sorting on Views' Math expressions
> - can process Webform submissions
> - lets you add your own custom aggregation functions
>
> ... and it puts summary statistics at the bottom of your aggregated table as well!